# How to use 'AND' within CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a SQL query to identify the role of an employee with regard to a device, and I'm getting the error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.` I'm not sure if it's possible to use the `AND` operator within `CASE`, if not is there any other operator I could use to accomplish this? The code I'm using is below.

```
SELECT custodian_id, manager_id, username,
CASE username
    WHEN custodian_id AND manager_id THEN 'Custodian and manager'
    WHEN manager_id THEN 'Manager'
    WHEN custodian_id THEN 'Custodian'
    ELSE ''
END AS person_role
FROM Install
ORDER BY person_role
```

Comment: May be you you want to check for existence of `custodian_id` and `manager_id` in the result?

Comment: what is data type of custodian_id and manager_id? Remember that the when clause needs a True/False condition.. if what you are looking is to check for the existence you can use custodian_id is not null , or manager_id is not null

Comment: For some rows in the table both of these fields are null... would that cause problems with this code?

Comment: @Jim . . . You have not provide sample data but it seems suspicious that something called "name" is being compared to something called "id".

Comment: @Gordon they have the same type and value for corresponding employees, that's not the issue

Comment: Post sample data of the table

Comment: @Jim Good coding starts with choosing good names.

Comment: @Smor I didn't create this database...

Comment: Since they are the same type and value you may consider using a different format for case: case when username = custodian_id and username = manager_id then .... when username = custodian_id ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a simple `case`.  Use a searched `case` expression instead:

```
SELECT custodian_id, manager_id, username,
       (CASE WHEN username = custodian_id and username = manager_id THEN 'Custodian and manager'
             WHEN username = manager_id THEN 'Manager'
             WHEN username = custodian_id THEN 'Custodian'
             ELSE ''
        END) AS person_role
FROM Install
ORDER BY person_role
```

Comment: What is the need for the 2nd and 3d WHEN in the CASE statement since if the 1st fails then the other 2 will fail too?

Comment: This does exactly what I want, thanks so much Gordon

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use parenthesis, as it's the evaluation of the expression.

This should work:

```
SELECT custodian_id, manager_id, username,
CASE username
    WHEN (custodian_id AND manager_id) THEN 'Custodian and manager'
    WHEN manager_id THEN 'Manager'
    WHEN custodian_id THEN 'Custodian'
    ELSE ''
END AS person_role
FROM Install
ORDER BY person_role
```

EDIT: I think you should also consider a condition for the columns, like check if the len is 0...

Comment: Sorry, i editted the post. didn't notice there was no condition for the columns. What you want to check there? If empty?

Comment: Do you want to check if both columns are 0?

Comment: If the fields `custodian_id` and `manager_id` are both null for a particular row then `person_role` should also be null... does my code not give this desired result?

Comment: It doesn't. This is considered a syntax error, it doesn't works as Python, for example. You should use ISNULL(), or some statement that returns TRUE or FALSE to evaluate the SQL function.

Comment: Is this true even though `username` is never null?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to try something like this:

```
SELECT custodian_id, manager_id, username,
CASE username
    WHEN custodian_id = username AND manager_id = username THEN 'Custodian and manager'
    WHEN manager_id THEN 'Manager'
    WHEN custodian_id THEN 'Custodian'
    ELSE ''
END AS person_role
FROM Install
ORDER BY person_role
```

Comment: You need to use the "searched case" form (as Gordon did) but with this logic. Use "case when username = custodian_id and username = manager_id then ... when username = manager_id then ... when user_name = custodian_id then ... else ... end".

Answer (score 0):

Case statement have to be like this:
select employee, case category_id when 1 then 'value 1' when 2 then 'value 2' else 'value x' 
from Employee